# Как правильно объяснить обособление приложений?

Tags: обособление

А нужно ли вообще уметь что-либо объяснять, может быть, достаточно ставить знаки препинания по интуиции? Я хочу привести примеры предложений с обособленными приложениями, в которых, как мне кажется, объяснение дается  не совсем правильно, но при этом решение об обособлении обычно принимается однозначно. А как вы определяете правильность постановки запятой в  приведенных ниже примерах?

А) Неведомый странник, голубь прячется от грозы на крыше. Несчастью верная сестра, надежда в мрачном подземелье разбудит бодрость и веселье.

Б) Прекрасные пловцы, пингвины могут жить на воде месяцами. Большой любитель книг, старик стал рыться на полках книжной лавки.

Comment: Niemand, а куда поступают абитуриенты, у которых "сплошь 90-100 баллов по русскому, а 80 - уже плохо"?

По статистике средний балл на ЕГЭ по русскому языку в 2014 году снизился по сравнению с прошлым годом (64 балла) и составил 62,5 балла, количество высокобалльных работ (80-100 баллов) — 13,2%, сообщил журналистам глава Рособрнадзора Сергей Кравцов.

Comment: В этом году списывали гораздо меньше.

Comment: София, поступают в питерский университет, в питерскую Вышку (Высшая школа экономики), в Политех, в Финэк... Причём далеко не все попадают на филфак и на лингвистику, а так – на экономику да на социологию...

Про Москву не знаю, но там, естественно, баллы ещё выше. 85 по русскому – это ничто.

Это ж как у Жванецкого: сижу дома – кажется, все дома сидят. Вышел на улицу – кажется, что все вышли... Смотря в каком кругу общаться... А представляете – средний балл был бы не 62, а 90? Да хотя бы 80... Куда их девать!? Они ведь к станку не пойдут...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Розенталь, помнится, объясняет такие случаи наличием у приложения, стоящего перед определяемым словом, добавочного обстоятельственного значения. Это вполне подходит ко всем приводимым Вами примерам. Здесь эти приложения можно мысленно заменить деепричастными оборотами (являясь неведомым странником, являясь несчастью верной сестрой...)

Comment: Виктор, я специально разделила предложения на две группы. Во второй группе обстоятельственное (причинное) значение явно присутствует, можно подставить "так как, будучи". Но в первой группе причинного значения нет, там приложения/определения  оформлены как попутные сообщения: голубь - неведомый странник, надежда - несчастью верная сестра, а затем следует основное сообщение. И замена деепричастием не кажется правильным, и голубь прячется под крышей не потому, что он неведомый странник.

Answer (score 6):

```
   Решение об обособлении обычно принимается однозначно.
```

А как иначе, если РАСПРОСТРАНЁННОЕ приложение, относящееся к НАРИЦАТЕЛЬНОМУ существительному,обособляется ВСЕГДА, независимо от положения? Валгина об этом сразу пишет, Розенталь расписывает:чаще всего в постпозиции,но и в препозиции тоже:
[XXIV. ЗНАКИ ПРЕПИНАНИЯ В ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯХ С ОБОСОБЛЕННЫМИ ЧЛЕНАМИ](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/45.htm)

Грамота.ру подтверждает  [Обособление приложений | gramota.ru](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_176)

А если говорить об обстоятельственном значении, так ведь, кроме причинного, есть ещё уступительное:

А) Неведомый странник, голубь прячется от грозы на крыше.(Несмотря на то, что голубь - странник, привык к грозам, он всё же прячется.) Несчастью верная сестра, надежда в мрачном подземелье разбудит бодрость и веселье. (Несмотря на то, что надежда -верная сестра несчастью, она разбудит бодрость и веселье)

Именно это и подсказывает Вам интуиция, которой у Розенталя и Валгиной тоже не занимать, они просто описали всё подробно, чтобы не путались те, у кого с интуицией проблемы.

Comment: Я как раз и говорю о том, что если такие приложения всегда обособляются, то и надо называть ЭТУ ПРИЧИНУ ОБОСОБЛЕНИЯ, а не обстоятельственное значение, или  несочетаемость с местоимением, или позицию после определяемого слова, или еще что. Это всё сопутствующие признаки, но не причина обособления. Кстати, зачем Вы начинаете искать это обстоятельственное значение, нет его в примерах №2. Там имеет место актуализация признака, выраженного приложением, имеющим чисто определительное значение, и это достаточная причина, чтобы его обособить.

Comment: Да во всех примерах есть обстоятельственное значение, если можно подставить "будучи", а здесь можно. Только обстоятельственное значение обычно ищут в определении, стоящем перед определяемым словом. Не знаю, с кем Вы спорите в попытках объяснить обособление, у меня, например, никогда с приложением сомнений не было: распространённое, относится к нарицательному имени - обособляй. Нераспространённое - тогда смотри, к чему относится и где стоит.

Comment: А вот  "актуализация признака, выраженного приложением, имеющим чисто определительное значение,- это достаточная причина, чтобы его обособить". Это круто. Это Вы кому? Школьникам? Или кто-то из филологов не обособил и Вы спорите с ним?

Comment: Нет, это я Вам говорю, надеясь, что Вы меня поймете правильно. А детям можно объяснить другими словами. Можно сказать, что обособленное приложение - это аналог придаточного  предложения (определительного или обстоятельственного). Фактически в этом случае мы как бы имеем два сообщения. И вот еще вопрос. Имеется предложение "Но мой добрый старик дворецкий, по-видимому, не оценил этого". Здесь "добрый старик" - это распространенное приложение?

Comment: "Старика" здесь нельзя отрывать от "дворецкого", какое же это приложение... Сначала "старик дворецкий" (старый дворецкий), а потому уж "добрый" присобачиваем.

Comment: "Но мой добрый старик дворецкий, по-видимому, не оценил этого". Нет. Дворецкий - подлежащее.Какой? добрый - определение.Он какой? есть кто? - старик - одиночное приложение, относится к нарицательному сущ.,но стоит впереди определяемого подлежащего, возможна замена прилагательным СТАРЫЙ,потому дефис не ставится.

Comment: Есть еще  написания на эту тему: маленький зверек коала, неутомимая бабочка махаон.(Есть интересные написания с дефисом: старенький немец-аптекарь).  Всё это редкие случаи необособленных приложений, когда определяемое сущ. является нарицательным, а в остальных случаях распространенное приложение обособляется. Со всеми  этими написаниями несложно ознакомить школьников,составить для них своеобразный атлас возможных форм. Надо воспитывать в людях орфографическое мировоззрение, что намного полезнее, чем заучивание правил.

Comment: Вот и воспитывайте, я уже отвоспитывалась. Только где ж Вы нашли здесь " редкие случаи необособленных приложений? Здесь всё по правилам. Маленький зверек коала, неутомимая бабочка махаон - нет дефиса при ОДИНОЧНОМ приложении, потому что в сочетании двух нарицательных сущ. первое обозначает родовое понятие, второе - видовое(как птица зяблик).Немец-аптекарь чем интересно написание? Два нарицательных сущ., второе понятие не является обозначением вида, это профессия. Здесь возможно обособление и с помощью запятых.

Comment: Вы путаете распространённое приложение с одиночным или за приложение принимаете подлежащее, что часто случается.Неутомимая бабочка какая?-по названию махаон. Махаон - одиночное приложение.Кто? аптекарь. Он какой?Старенький.определение.Он кто по национальности? Немец.-приложение. Хотя здесь возможно наоборот, но два нарицательных сущ. слились в одно понятие,написание полуслитное, их соединяет дефис.Ничего "интересного"здесь как раз нет.Никакой атлас возможных форм составлять не надо, пусть просто выучат правила.И Вам их вспомнить не помешает, а не выдумывать новые.

Comment: Да будет так, что тут еще скажешь. Всё у нас замечательно, все ученики грамотные,  они с удовольствием учат правила под мудрым руководством своих наставников, что и показал  ЕГЭ в 2014 году. Всё у нас идеально,  поэтому скажем решительное нет орфографическим атласам и прочим выдумкам.

Comment: Правда, остается один вопрос по поводу эмоций. Зачем превращать спокойный обмен мнениями между людьми в неприятное разбирательство? И как-то не очень этичны ваши замечания вида "вы путаете, вы не понимаете" - думаю, надо выбирать более вежливые слова. Да и про птичек зябликов я всё знаю, и подлежащее от приложения вполне могу отличить. Вы просто даже не потрудились понять мою мысль, но в дальнейшем я уж не буду вас утруждать своими размышлениями.

Comment: >> Всё у нас замечательно, все ученики грамотные, они с удовольствием учат правила под мудрым руководством своих наставников, что и показал ЕГЭ в 2014 году.

Не могут быть ВСЕ идеально грамотными. И половина не может, и даже четверть. Иначе как мы отличим умного от дурака? )))
А уж в плачевных результатах ЕГЭ меньше всего виноваты сложные правила. Что, грамотность сильно упала за последние 20 лет потому что за эти 20 лет правила сильно усложнились? - Смешно. Не там вы ищете причину.

Дочка у меня сейчас поступает, а я смотрю списки абитуриентов: сплошь 90-100 баллов по русскому! 80 - уже плох

Comment: Никакие замечательные правила ученики с удовольствием учить не будут.

Comment: Ну почему... Есть же те, кому нравится русский язык. Я это точно знаю. ))) Учить – не в смысле зубрить, конечно.